# Powerbi and Azure DevOps (online version) reporting when Backlog Level name changes

Tags: azure-devops, powerbi, analytics

I'm attempting to utilize Power BI and the Analytics Views provided in Azure DevOps to create reports.  I noticed an issue regarding the template(s) used that caused for no data to appear in the datasets in Power BI.

Scenario: If a user uses the Scrum template in Azure DevOps, it calls the Refinement Backlog level of work "Backlog items". If a user goes into change that to "Stories" it changes how the queries grab the group of work items in that level.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQ8cT.jpg) You can easily change the query to match the new name of the backlog level. You cannot add multiple "projects" to that query and see the data in the dataset if other projects are using the default name.

**Issue**:  I attempted to change the name back to the original name of "Backlog items" instead of "Stories" and run the query in the Analytics Views to grab the data from multiple projects with the same "Backlog items" level but nothing appears in that project that was renamed back to the original name.

How to reproduce:

1. Open a project in Azure DevOps
2. Access Analytics Views
3. Under any Backlog query, edit and add additional projects to retrieve data in this view and save
4. Open Power BI and connect to the recently changed query
5. In Azure DevOps, access Organization Settings and go to Process
6. Access the project the above query is located and open the template
7. Modify the name of the backlog level to something other than "Backlog items"[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ukyui.jpg)
8. Save and go back to Power BI and refresh data
9. Actual result - you should not see the data from that project due to the name change
10. Go back and change the name back to the original name and refresh the dataset in Power BI

Result:
You still do not see the deta in the dataset even though you renamed it back to the original name.  Besides 'resetting' the backlog level back to the original default state, is there a way to get it to recognize the original name if you renamed it back?  Is there another step to making it recognize the name change? Since it's in the cloud, I waited 24 hours after the name change back to the original name but still didn't work. I noticed the same thing will happen on the Portfolio Backlog level (i.e. Epic).

Comment: Hi friend, is there any update for this issue?

Comment: Took me a while to verify but that looks to have done the trick.  I didn't really want to reset but doesn't seem like any other way.

Comment: If my answer helps to resolve your issue, would you please [accepting it as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)? So that more members can see this useful info and we can archive this issue. Thanks~

Answer (score 0):

> Besides 'resetting' the backlog level back to the original default
>   state, is there a way to get it to recognize the original name if you
>   renamed it back?

I seem to reproduce similar issue like yours and then I use steps below to make it work:

1.Reset the Backlog and refresh the page.

[image]

2.Then navigate to the `Analytics views`, edit the View(the view in your step3) which can't be recognized now.

[image]

No matter it's `Backlog items backlog` or `Stories backlog` here, delete them all and `Verify the view`. Then click **Save** button.

[image]

3.Refresh current page and edit the View again, add the `Backlog Items backlog` back, Verify the view, Save the view. Now refresh the data in Power BI, the data should come back.

Above steps are what I use to work around the issue, hope it helps :)